# Connecting Snowflake database to R and Python in Datagrip

Tags: python, r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datagrip, intellij-datagrip

I'm struggling with a fairly basic setup.  I have downloaded both the R & Python plug-ins in Datagrip... how do I connect these to my Snowflake database in Datagrip?

Comment: Are you connected to Snowflake from Datagrip successfully?  If not, I put a few articles below to help. If so, then what issues or errors are you seeing with the plug-ins? 

https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/How-to-Configure-Snowflake-connections-for-Datagrip

https://medium.com/@beglinursahedov/connecting-to-snowflake-using-datagrip-and-okta-sso-48c38cb794e3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The R and Python plugins in DataGrip are only simple editor-support extensions to work with Python and R files within the same IDE (instead of opening a separate editor program).

Your DataGrip's configured Connections will not automatically be available in the Python/R code you edit in the same IDE using the plugins. Instead, you'll have to follow language-specific instructions to connect to Snowflake directly in your code.

For Python, an official connection guide is offered at https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector.html
For R, a blog post covers one possible approach with dplyr at https://www.snowflake.com/blog/integrating-the-snowflake-data-warehouse-with-r-via-dplyr/